# How to reload the modified files without restarting in pylons?

Tags: python, pylons, reload

I'm using pylons, and using this command to start the server:

```
paster serve --reload development.ini
```

I found when I modify something, the paster will reload the application. In the console, it shows:

```
-------------------- Restarting --------------------
Starting server in PID 7476.
serving on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

This is convenient but not enough, because it will cost 5 seconds more or less each time. If I refresh that page and the server is not reloaded completely yet, the page will display the old content, and I don't know if it is the lastest content, so I had to refresh the page several times to make sure.

I wonder if there is a better way to read the modified content without reloading, or find a quicker reloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To controllers, you can configure Routes to rescan the directory controllers without restart application:

http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/controllers/#adding-controllers-dynamically

Comment: It seems only support **adding new controllers**, but not **modifing**. I tried and start `paster` without `--reload` option, but modified controller can't be reload. Do you successfully reload the modified controller without restarting?